how to do pagination in Google Get Place Details by PlaceID?
I've used the below cURL to fetch reviews and I'm getting only 5 out of 1000+ reviews. There is no next_page_token in the response. How do I get the remaining reviews?
SAMPLE cURL: curl -L -X GET 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?place_id=ChIJN1t_tDeuEmsRUsoyG83frY4&fields=name%2Crating%2Cformatted_phone_number&key=YOUR_API_KEY'

Please advise.

I'm able to call the API and get the first 5 reviews and get "user_ratings_total": 12.
There is no next_page_token in the response.
How to get the remaining reviews?
I'm trying to call this API in a Logic App.


This is in line with the documentation:

A JSON array of up to five reviews.

For your business, you can use the Business Profile APIs.
Another option is to use scrapers, of course.
